# Android: reference to a dynamic View is no longer valid after screen rotation

Tags: android, reference, screen-rotation

Context:

i have *n* dynamically created ImageView(s) in an activity.

when an imageview is touched:
   1) an IV object reference is stored vis the onTouch event.
   2) a dialog opens; allowing the user to edit the image.

when the user has finished making edits, the changes are applied to the object which we have a stored reference.

however, if the user rotates the device while the Dialog is open, the activity is recreated; and the reference to the selected ImageView is no longer valid.

Issue:

So, the problem is that the recreated ImageView, produced from the rotation event, has a different reference to the reference that i have stored, meaning that i have no idea which ImageView to apply my edits to..

This seems like a common issue that could easily be solved, but i don't know how..

because the ImageView(s) are dynamically created, and there could be *n* quantity, i can't find view by ID.

i can't set a tag, as it is lost when the IV is recreated.

i read something about retainInstanceState, but this appears to be for fragments; not activities

Answer (score 0):

Assign ids to your generated ImageViews. When dialog is shown you pass this id to dialog, when dialog finishes it returns your values and this id, then you just get ImageView by id, be it a new one, or old doesn't matter since the couple 'id - iv at position' are the same no matter how many times you recreate activities.

As example:

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setId(1337 + i); // Spice things up a little :D
    addView(iv);
}
```

Then just pass required id `iv.getId()` to dialog, and when dialog finishes get iv by calling `findViewById(id);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to add `android:configChanges="orientation|<whatever other flags you need>"` to your `<activity>` in AnroidManifest.xml, so the activity won't be recreated when orientation changes. However, using this method is [officially discouraged](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config):

> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort

Another way would be to store in the dialog not the reference to `ImageView`, but its `id` instead.